# Is it possible to force chromium show the "window control icons" on the left

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, chrome, xfce

I'm not running Gnome or Ubuntu,

[image]

But I also want those (minimize, maximze, close) icons to be visible on the left as well,
without touching the source code, is there any way to make it work ?

**EDIT**

I prefer the icon s provided by chromium, I uploaded the wrong screenshot, it's updated now !

I'm on XFCE4, Arch Linux

**EDIT2**

Hmm, read part of the source code, and I nailed it with a very dirty method, but still looking for other methods ...

[image]

Comment: In the case you rely on xfwm as your window manager i don't know if the developers intended to adjust such setting. But if you like mutter, the default window manager of unity it should be no problem to replace xfwm by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out chromium reads about gconf if metacity is the current window manager.

Otherwise it uses a default icon string to build the layout, which is:

`:minimize,maximize,close`

So, it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is pretty easy to do in xfce4 as window decorations are handled by xfwm4 which can be configured fairly straight forward.

You go to your `Settings Manager->Window Manager` and simply rearrange the titlebar items on the left in whatever fashion you want.

**PS.** The one in Ubuntu supposedly follows the gconf `/apps/metacity/general/button_layout` key, but I'm on arch too and can't seem to make it work.

Comment: I uploaded the wrong screenshot .. updatd

Comment: then you might be at a loss, I think they are hardcoded